# Dealing with illegal arrays

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop

Some context: This program reads lines of Stone and puts them onto the map.

The program should first ask for the number of lines of STONEs as an integer. Then, the program will scan the locations of the lines as a group of four integers in the following format:

row column length value

The row and column represent the left-most block of a horizontal line of blocks to the placed on the map. The length tells you how many stones should be in this horizontal line. In this example, assume the fourth integer to always be 1 representing a stone.

Example: CommandMeaning

0 0 5 1 Place a line of stone starting at [0][0] and ending at [0][4]. All 5 squares in the line will be set to 1 (STONE).

NOTE: It is possible for the first three integers (row column length) to result in a line which is partially or wholly outside of the map. If this is the case, you should ignore this line completely and not make any changes to the map.

THUS PROBLEM: when i enter illegal array values, e.g. 22 22 22 1, it simple stops the program and says there has been an error. How do i get the program to simply ignore that line of command and continue with the rest as if it was never entered?

```
#define SIZE 15
#define EMPTY 0
#define STONE 1

void printMap(int map[SIZE][SIZE], int playerX);

int main (void) {
    // This line creates our 2D array called "map" and sets all
    // of the blocks in the map to EMPTY.
    int map[SIZE][SIZE] = {EMPTY};

    int playerX = SIZE / 2;

    printf("How many lines of stone? ");
    int linesOfStone; 
    scanf("%d", &linesOfStone);

    printf("Enter lines of stone:\n");
  
    int rowPos; 
    int columnPos; 
    int stoneLength; 
    int stoneValue; 
   
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < linesOfStone) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rowPos, &columnPos, &stoneLength, &stoneValue); 

//ERROR ERROR this is where i attempt to fix tackle the problem but my logic seems lost... 
        if (rowPos < 0 || columnPos < 0) {
        rowPos = 0; 
        columnPos = 0; 
        map[0][0] = 0; 
        } else if (rowPos > SIZE || columnPos > SIZE) {
        rowPos = 0; 
        columnPos = 0; 
        map[0][0] = 0; 
        } else {
        map[rowPos][columnPos] = stoneValue; 
        }
        
            int j = 0; 
            while (j < stoneLength) { 
            map[rowPos][columnPos + j] = 1; 
            j++; 
            }
    i++; 
    }


    printMap(map, playerX);

    return 0;
}


void printMap(int map[SIZE][SIZE], int playerX) {
    
    // Print values from the map array.
    int i = 0;
    while (i < SIZE) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < SIZE) {
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }    
    
    // Print the player line.
    i = 0;
    while (i < playerX) {
        printf("  ");
        i++;
    }
    printf("P\n");
}
```

Comment: You already have some validation, where you check `rowPos` and `columnPos` against `0` and `SIZE`. Besides that the check against `SIZE` needs to be e.g. `rowPos >= SIZE` you already have the check you ask for. What else do you want? Perhaps the problem is somewhere else in the program? Have you tried to use a debugger to catch any possible crash and see where in your code it happens?

Comment: Are you looking for the `continue` statement? Or just check the opposite condition and wait for the loop to go again.

Answer (score 0):

**Off by one**

`rowPos > SIZE` should `rowPos >= SIZE`.   Same for `columnPos > SIZE`.

Recommend an additional test to insure within `stoneLength`.

**No range limit on `stoneLength`**

**Range limits best applied inpedentalty**

```
//if (rowPos < 0 || columnPos < 0) {
if (rowPos < 0) {
```

Comment: "Range limits best applied inpedentalty" why do you think so? Lines with invalid values should be ignored, so I think all limits should be checked in one place so that we need only single code to ignore.

Comment: @MikeCAT Disagree with " Lines with invalid values should be ignored,".  OP presently is attempting to simply limit the range, and continue. This answer refines that approach. IMO, the errant line should not get ignored, but generate an error message.

Comment: But the questions says "How do i get the program to simply ignore that line of command and continue with the rest as if it was never entered?"

Comment: @MikeCAT OP can ignore that line or not, print an error or not, up to OP.  I still maintain better to untangle the input validation.  The goal is clarity - which can benefit with multiple lines - not code golf - trying to minimize source code length.

Answer (score 0):

Lines with valid format and out-of-range value like `22 22 22 1` can be rejected by checking the values and ignore via `if` statement.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < linesOfStone) {
    /* abort on unexpected input failure */
    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rowPos, &columnPos, &stoneLength, &stoneValue) != 4) return 1;

    /* check values and deal with that only of all of them are valid */
    if (0 <= rowPos && rowPos < SIZE && 0 <= columnPos && columnPos < SIZE &&
    0 <= stoneLength && columnPos + stoneLength <= SIZE && (stoneValue == 0 || stoneValue == 1)) {
        int j = 0; 
        while (j < stoneLength) { 
            map[rowPos][columnPos + j] = 1; 
            j++; 
        }
        i++; 
    }
}
```

To deal with lines with invalid format like `hello world`, you can read lines via `fgets` and parse the line via `sscanf`.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < linesOfStone) {
    char line[102400]; /* believing that extremely long line won't come... */
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) return 1; /* abort on unexpected input failure */
    /* ignore the line if parsing failed */
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d", &rowPos, &columnPos, &stoneLength, &stoneValue)) != 4) continue;

    /* same logic as above */
}
```